# window.location.href stopped working recently on Excel for Mac?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

In a Javascript based Excel add-in, it navigates to a third party oauth sign-in page using the following code:

```
window.location.href = "https://app.hubspot.com/oauth/authorize";
```

It has been working well on Excel 2016 for Mac (version 16.9 (180116)) until recently.  Now it won't navigate to the 3rd party sign-in page anymore.  There is no change in add-in manifest and the 3rd party domain is whitelisted in there as well.  The same code and manifest are still working with Excel for Windows and Excel Online.

```
<AppDomain>https://app.hubspot.com/</AppDomain>
```

I think the way Excel for Mac supports the `window.location.href` was changed recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug/regression; I have passed this on to one of my colleagues to investigate.

I opened bug https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/59 to track this.  Feel free to subscribe to the issue status there -- and thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Subscribed.

Comment: A workaround was suggested on the github issue and it solved my problem.    Thanks!  The workaround is to remove the ending '/' character in the whitelisted domains in the manifest,
 e.g., <AppDomain>https://app.hubspot.com</AppDomain>